# Is there a way to do vertical sorting with multiple font sizes in qml text?

Tags: html, qt, qml

Can I use vertical center alignment when there are multiple font sizes in a text line in a qml text item?

html span about vertical alignment

```
Text {
        id: element
        x: 81
        y: 234
        width: 427
        height: 63
        text: "> Menu > " +
              "<span style='font-size:20px;'><b>Setting Mode > </b></span>" + 
              "<span style='font-size:24px;'><b>Setting Mode</b></span>"
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: 16
    }
```

The three words will be output in vertical bottom. Is there a way to output the vertical center alignment?

Comment: It would be easier to do that if you'd replace the html by QML. Why do you want to use html code?

Comment: I can divide text items, but I want to use the html grammar because it has to display the string displayed on one line and the length changes with multilingual support.

Comment: You don't need html for that (it's quite easy to define the font size regarding the length of the text). So, it seems you are trying to fix your solution instead of answering your problem. Could you be more specific on what you want to achieve and explain your whole problem?